# How to split a string, where one character is a separator, and the other one is content

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string, which contains two special characters: `"a"` and `"x"` (like `"aaxaxbcdxbcdexaxdefxdefa"`), and I would like to split it according to these rules:

- In case an `"a"` is encountered, the result string will contain this as a single character.
- In case an `"x"` is encountered, this will be used as a separator.

So, I would like this:

```
Stretched out input:
   a    a x  a x  bcd x  bcde x  a x  def x  def    a

{ "a", "a", "a", "bcd", "bcde", "a", "def", "def", "a" }
```

Obviously, I can use this for splitting, based on the `"x"`:

```
string infoList[] = input_string.Split(new char[] {"x"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But the story with the `"a"` makes me think of enlarging already existing arrays (of which I fear it might cause a performance problem). In top of this, I believe there should be some oneliner for this (instead of writing my own `for`-loop).

**Edit**
Simply said: is there a `string.Split(...)` that does not remove the separator from the final string?

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You should not use strings like that, especially if you're transmitting user input! use serialization or at least do proper escaping

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I think you've commented the wrong question

Comment: @Cid you're right, sorry, the question looked very similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple : Replace each `"a"` by `"xax"` and split the same way you did :

```
var input_string = "aaxaxbcdxbcdexaxdefxdefa";
input_string = input_string.Replace("a", "xax");
var infoList = input_string.Split(new char[] {'x'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", infoList));
```

This outputs

```
a, a, a, bcd, bcde, a, def, def, a
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is yet another possibility: if we out `a|[^ax]+` pattern we'll have either single `a` match or a sequence without `x` or `a`

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ... 

  string input_string = "aaxaxbcdxbcdexaxdefxdefa";

  string[] infoList = Regex
    .Matches(input_string, "a|[^ax]+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", infoList));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  a, a, a, bcd, bcde, a, def, def, a
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested solutions are short and nice (I'd use them in 99% of cases) but in case performance is your concern the best solution will be plain old for-loop.

```
public List<string> Split(string s)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        var i = 0;
        var substringStart = 0;

        while (i < s.Length)
        {
            switch (s[i])
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'x':
                    if(substringStart != i)
                        results.Add(s.Substring(substringStart, i - substringStart));

                    if(s[i] == 'a')
                        results.Add("a");

                    substringStart = i + 1;
                    break;
            }

            ++i;
        }

        if(substringStart != i)
            results.Add(s.Substring(substringStart, i - substringStart));

        return results;
    }
```